# Wifi-connect works in bash but not in crontab

Tags: unix, cron, raspberry-pi

I use wifi-connect to configure my Raspberry Pi in unknown WLAN Networks.

wifi-connect works when I execute it via command line once the system booted, but when I put it into sudo crontab -e, it won't work. The cron logs show no errors. The autostart of my own scripts works.

My crontab:
@reboot /usr/local/sbin/wifi-connect

Does someone have a hint for me why this does not work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually this kind of issues (when things works in a terminal but not in crontab), since there is nothing tricky in the crontab entry (you are just calling a executable with no arguments) are due to timing issue. Likely the crontab entry get executed before the network stack is ready. To do a quick test add a delay to that execution prepending `sleep 60;` to your command, this will delay the execution of 1 minute, which should be enough. Anyway this is not a reliable solution, you will have to user a script o a service which actually check for the network stack.

Comment: Hm yeah I already tried it with a 10 second delay but I will try with 60 seconds as well. Could you give me a hint for what exactly I have to check if I want to write a script? Whether the network drivers are loaded?

Comment: take a look here: https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/NetworkTarget/

Comment: Thank you so much! I tried it with a 20 second delay and it works. I also had to add a "sudo" before the command despite it beeing in "sudo crontab -e". Weird. Well, I will look into writing a script to check for the network stack. Thanks again!